# In SQL Server, sqlcmd with -E option works, but same command with -U & -P for the same account doesn't - I get a "login failed"

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

In SQL Server, the sqlcmd with -E option works, but same command with -U & -P for the same account doesn't - I get a "login failed"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `-U` and `-P` specify SQL logins. You cannot use a Windows account name/password to log in with these (as I suspect you're doing). Either use a SQL account, or use the Credential Manager in Windows to set up a username/password for `servername:1433`; then `-E` will use that. Alternatively, set up a new context with `runas` first (if the credentials need to be variable).

Comment: Using a SQL account did the trick.  Thanks!